# How to upload/download files directly from Google Drive to the browser without using server bandwidth?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to make a web app where the only cost to me is serving the webpage to the user, and all their data is saved to their Google Drive so I don't have to pay for storage or bandwidth.

Is this possible using Google Drive?

I can't see how:

- If I want to save something directly from the browser, it needs my application's API key, and I can't put that in the HTML as it is non-secure.
- If I try to do anything where the webpage calls my server, the file will have to pass through my server to get to Google.

Comment: Are you wanting to use your own Google Drive (same account for all users) or have users sign into their personal google drive accounts when they use your application, and save the data there?

Comment: their user account. thanks, updated the question

Comment: Ok well you can use JavaScript and the browser will talk to the Google API directly. Google made a whole JavaScript library for that. It's quite well described in their documentation and there are examples etc

Comment: @ADyson Do you mean Apps Script? Or a Drive API JS client?

Comment: I mean the Google APIs JS client, yes. https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Comment: @ADyson, yes, their Javascript API is one of the first things in the documentation - but it needs you to include the application key, which is fine for personal use, but you can't upload your secret app key to every user - as I described in the first bullet point in my question. Unless you don't have to or I'm misunderstanding security here?

Comment: If it wasn't secure, they wouldn't write it like that. Google are not some amateur jokers. The API key is tied to your website's domain, it can't be used for AJAX requests outside your site / domain (because you have to register the allowed domain(s) in the google developer portal). And it's not intended to be totally secret. Don't confuse the API key with OAuth client secrets ( which you'd use for server-to-server requests). Even if someone steals it successfully (but why would they, when they can get their own for free?) it doesn't give them access to anything of yours.

Comment: Anyway if you want the browser to talk to Google without the overhead of going via your server, then you have to use the Javascript client (or more painfully, write your own AJAX requests...but you still need the API key to send in those requests). So you don't have much option really.

Comment: I don't know if I'm making my concern clear: Google needs a secret key (API key, password, whatever you want to call it) to know it's MY app making the call. If I make this key public by putting it in the HTML then anyone anywhere could use that key to make calls to Google masquerading as me and get my users' data, couldn't they? Or if they'd need the user's key too, then at least they could build a fake page using my app key (like a forgery attack).

Comment: `Google needs a secret key`..except it's not secret. It's not a password. You supply the API key / client ID. The user supplies username and password when the script prompts them. There is a different OAuth flow for server-side applications which requires secrets. This isn't it. `If I make this key public by putting it in the HTML then anyone anywhere could use that key to make calls to Google masquerading as me`...no, because the API key is tied to your website and its domain, as I already mentioned. Read this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

Comment: P.S. I appreciate this stuff isn't simple. It took me a while to get my head round all the different bits when I first wrote applications which interacted with google APIs. But once you do, it's good, and it works well. Be patient, read it a few times (and maybe compare it to the server-side options) until you grasp all the bits and pieces. Better still, try it out, it doesn't take too long to setup (and you can specify localhost as an allowed domain for testing) and then it's much easier to get the idea.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll proceed assuming the browser API will work, and if I still have doubts later will post something on the security stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to save something directly from the browser, it needs my application's API key, and I can't put that in the HTML as it is non-secure.

You need client credentials, api key will only give you access to public data and wont give you the ability to write anything.  Web credentials if configured properly are bound to the domain that they are intended to be use for there for they are considered secure.

> If I try to do anything where the webpage calls my server, the file will have to pass through my server to get to Google.

Well this is true considering that your server is running the code.  There is no way to route directly from the client to the user. Unless you did this with javascript in which case the code is running client sided and running in the users browser.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what your answer is here. If yes, then how exactly?

Comment: @Richard stack overflow isn't here to provide you with solutions to your issues.  You asked a very vague question about if something is possible.    Im giving you some corrections and some ideas on how you can achieve it.  I cant build your solution for you.  Why not give it a try and come back if you have any issues.